# Running multiple unit test projects in Jenkins only records second set of results

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, nunit-console

I have searched for a while and can't find an answer on here for the first time ever.

I have a solution which contains multiple C# projects.  Two of these projects are unit test projects.  I am building this solution with Jenkins, attempting to run all the unit tests, then packaging it for an internal NuGet server.

The issue I am having is that I am running the tests for one unit test project after the other, I think this is causing the second set of tests to save their results over the first set because I can see in the console output that both sets of tests ran and passed, however the Test Results in Jenkins only shows the second set of tests.

I am running these with a windows batch command using nunit-console like this:

```
nunit-console.exe MyFirstProject.UnitTests/bin/Debug/MyFirstProject.UnitTests.dll
nunit-console.exe MySecondProject.UnitTests/bin/Debug/MySecondProject.UnitTests.dll
```

Is there a better way I can run these so that all test results are recorded?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out.  For anyone who runs into this it's quite simple, you just have to put both (or however many) assemblies in the same command like this:

```
nunit-console.exe MyFirstProject.UnitTests/bin/Debug/MyFirstProject.UnitTests.dll MySecondProject.UnitTests/bin/Debug/MySecondProject.UnitTests.dll
```

Now all my test results show up!

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to anyone else who has this type of issue:
 To get one report from two groups of tests run from the same assembly, define two Windows Batch Command build steps, each with its own category and result file :

```
"%nunit%\nunit-console.exe" "%WORKSPACE%\MyTests.sln" /include:TestCategory1 /xml=nunit-result1.xml
```

and

```
"%nunit%\nunit-console.exe" "%WORKSPACE%\MyTests.sln" /include:TestCategory2 /xml=nunit-result2.xml
```

Add a Post Build action to Publish the NUnit Test result report and define the XML filename as *.xml.

The Nunit plugin will concatenate the different test results into one result that can be viewed and emailed.

This way will also solve the OP's question.